# mySql Error in Query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have (3) tables: Professor, Comment, Course

I'm trying to get a few columns to display the professor with all the courses and all the comments they have.

My tables
[image]

[image: comment]

[image]

SQL:

```
  SELECT prefix, code, info, date
        FROM Course, Comment
        JOIN Professor ON Professor.pID = Comment.pID
        AND JOIN Course ON Course.cID = Comment.cID
        WHERE Comment.pID = ?
```

Throws error:
 Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN Course ON Course.cID = Comment.cID WHERE Comment.pID = '273'' at line 4

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT prefix, code, info, date
    FROM Comment
    JOIN Professor ON Professor.pID = Comment.pID
    JOIN Course ON Course.cID = Comment.cID
    WHERE Comment.pID = ?
```

Just remove the AND before the second JOIN and remove Course in the From list. You may need to change the order of the tables depending on what table data you are primarily after.

Advise that you have a read through the [MySQL JOIN syntax page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: Now it throws error: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Course'' in

Comment: Fixed. Remove the Course table in the From part.

Answer (score 0):

change 'AND JOIN' to just 'JOIN'

Answer (score 0):

There is no `AND JOIN`. Please [read about `JOIN` syntax in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) before attempting to use it.

Additionally, you reference table `Course` twice.